# How to save output from the shell?

Tags: arrays

I want to save this in a file form the shell:

```
Type the number of steps N
10
Type the initial values ti and ai
0
1
 23.000000 24.000000 
 46.000000 576.000000 
 69.000000 13824.000000 
 92.000000 331776.000000 
 115.000000 7962624.000000 
 138.000000 191102976.000000 
 161.000000 4586471424.000000 
 184.000000 110075314176.000000 
 207.000000 2641807540224.000000 
 230.000000 63403380965376.000000 
 253.000000 1521681143169024.000000
```

how to do it? it does not work by just typing:

```
>./a.out>lalalla.txt
```

Comment: Are you trying to capture the output of an interactive session with an executable into a file?

Comment: it does work, but since you have redirected the output to the text file, you cannot see anything. Try typing `10 0 1`

Comment: sorry , it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

do

```
script filename.txt
```

Run the program, then type exit at the prompt

The session will be in filename.txt

Comment: thanks!! it works but in the output file there are some another extra text, but It does not matter.